# How to insert input tag in web page using BHO VC++?

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, bho

I have created a BHO in VC++ refering below link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

now i need to add input tag while page load completes, i tried with below code

```
void STDMETHODCALLTYPE CTestBHO::OnDocumentComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *pvarURL)
{

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
    responseCode=200;
    setResponseCode(pDisp);
    }
}

void CRealBrowserBHO::setResponseCode(IDispatch *pDisp)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
CComPtr<IDispatch> spDispDoc;
hr = m_spWebBrowser->get_Document(&spDispDoc);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        BSTR inputElement=L"<input type=\"text\" name=\"ResponseCode\" value=\"200\">";
        IHTMLElement *pTRElmt = NULL;
        CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument2> spHTMLDoc = spDispDoc;
        HRESULT hr1=spHTMLDoc->get_body(&pTRElmt);
        if (spHTMLDoc != NULL)
        {
            HRESULT hr=pTRElmt->insertAdjacentHTML(L"beforeEnd",inputElement);
        }
    }
}
```

But the  tag didnt inserted on my web page.

What goes wrong, please point me what i missed here

Thanks,
Ramachandran.

Comment: Please indicate what calls fails. What is the value of the last hr?

Comment: Also, what is the test on hr in the OnDocumentComplete body? There is no HRESULT here...

Comment: Finally, don't store or pass BSTR which are NOT BSTR. Use CComBSTR InpEl( L"<input.../>); and insertAdjacentHTML( CComBSTR( L"beforeEnd") ,inpEl);

Comment: @manuell That worked thanks for your kind help :) . But i am facing another problem when i change the input type from "text" to "hidden" i cant find the input tag in html source (right click -> view source) what could be the reason?

Comment: I am currently using IE9 and can assure you that HTML element added via a BHO and insertAdjacentHTML are NOT visible in "view source", 'text' or 'hidden' doesn't matter in this regard. If your IE version is not too old, you could see the live HTML by using "Development Tools" (F12 in IE9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code that should work:

```
void CRealBrowserBHO::setResponseCode(IDispatch *pDisp)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spDispDoc;
    hr = m_spWebBrowser->get_Document(&spDispDoc);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spDispDoc)
    {
        CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> spHTMLDoc;
        hr = spDispDoc.QueryInterface<IHTMLDocument2>( &spHTMLDoc );
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spHTMLDoc) 
        {
            CComPtr<IHTMLElement> spBodyElmt;
            hr = spHTMLDoc->get_body(&spBodyElmt);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spBodyElmt)
            {
                CComBSTR inputElement( L"<input type='text' name='ResponseCode' value='200'/>" );
                hr = spBodyElmt->insertAdjacentHTML( CComBSTR( L"beforeEnd" ), inputElement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}